# Sidekiq scheduled jobs gets automatically deleted (Sidekiq + Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I want the worker to run on a specific date. I am able to schedule jobs in sidekiq. And sidekiq UI also shows scheduled jobs perfectly. But due to unknown reason my data on sidekiq (processed count,scheduled jobs etc.) gets deleted and everything is reset to 0 in sidekiq UI. Can someone please help me understand this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are calling flush on Redis, clearing all your data.

Comment: Thanks Mike, But I have same configuration at my local and its working fine but on my other server I am getting this problem.

Comment: There are commands to set flush but we could not find such. How can we check if Flush on Redis was called or not ?